# Fill in rows based on condition for grouped data using tidyr

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have the following dataframe of which I am trying to create the 'index2' field conditional on the 'index1' field:
[image]

Basically this data represents a succession of behaviours for different individual (ID) penguins and I am trying to index groups of behaviour (index 2) that incorporates all other behaviours  in between (and including) dives (which have been indexed into dive bouts = index 1). I would appreciate a tidyverse solution grouping by ID.

```
Reproducible: 
df<-data.frame(ID=c(rep('A',9),rep('B',14)),behaviour=c('surface','dive','dive','dive','surface','commute','surface','dive',   'dive','dive','dive','surface','dive','dive','commute','commute','surface','dive','dive','surface','dive','dive','surface'),index1=c(0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,0,0,0,3,3,0,3,3,0),index2=c(0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,0,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,0))
```

Comment: Please fix the formatting

Comment: It is not clear whether you had a typo.  Try `df1 %>% group_by(ID)  %>% mutate(Index2New = cummax(Index1))`

Comment: This solution does not account for behaviours that should not be indexed, i.e. the 0 value for surface behaviour in between 2 dive bouts for ID 'B' in the example. I need a solution that fills in the zeros only when they are in between the same dive bout index number in index1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function with `rle`

```
frle <- function(x) {
    rl <- rle(x)
    i1 <- cummax(rl$values)
    i2 <- c(i1[-1]  != i1[-length(i1)], FALSE)
    i1[i2] <- 0
    as.integer(inverse.rle(within.list(rl, values <- i1)))
 }
```

After grouping by 'ID', `mutate` the 'Index1' to get the expected column

```
library(dplyr) 
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Index2New = frle(Index1))
# A tibble: 19 x 5
# Groups: ID [2]
#   ID    behaviour Index1 Index2 Index2New
#   <chr> <chr>      <int>  <int>     <int>
# 1 A     surface        0      0         0
# 2 A     dive           1      1         1
# 3 A     dive           1      1         1
# 4 A     dive           1      1         1
# 5 A     surface        0      1         1
# 6 A     commute        0      1         1
# 7 A     surface        0      1         1
# 8 A     dive           1      1         1
# 9 A     dive           1      1         1
#10 B     dive           2      2         2
#11 B     dive           2      2         2
#12 B     surface        0      0         0
#13 B     dive           3      3         3
#14 B     dive           3      3         3
#15 B     commute        0      3         3
#16 B     commute        0      3         3
#17 B     surface        0      3         3
#18 B     dive           3      3         3
#19 B     dive           3      3         3
```

Comment: This works well for the example I provided but when I applied it to the full dataset I realised that there are instances when greater than 2 successive dive bouts with the same number occur. I have updated the reproducible example accordingly so if you run your code on this it does not account for this new situation.